# How can I print a MongoDB list in a jinja2 template?

Tags: python, jinja2

I have the 'affects' field in my MongoDB collection that I use to store a list of values. Looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51dc89712ef6af45b0a5f286"),
    "affects" : [
        "GS",
        "WEB",
        "DB",
        "CB",
        "ALL",
        "OTHER"
    ],
}
```

And in the template (html page) I do this:

```
{% for change in changes %}
{{ change._id }}
{{ change.affects }}
{% endfor %}
```

This works perfectly when your field has only one value, for example _id would output like this in my HTML page:

```
51dc89712ef6af45b0a5f286
```

When there's multiple values though, the output comes out like this:

```
[u'GS', u'WEB', u'DB', u'CB', u'ALL', u'OTHER']
```

Is there a way in jinja2 to iterate over the list of values and have them printed out without the brackets, quotes and u?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need a nested loop in Jinja, try this:

```
{% for change in changes %}
    {{ change._id }}
    {% for affect in change.affects %} 
        {{ affect }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ah, I tried something like that but I had the wrong syntax. It works with yours. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble with something similar, my fix...
flask app.py

```
@app.route('/mongo', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def mongo():

    # connect to database
    db = client.blog

    # specify the collections name
    posts = db.posts

    # convert the mongodb object to a list
    data = list(posts.find())

    return render_template('mongo_index.html', blog_info=data)
```

Then your jinja template might look something like this...
mongo_index.hmtl

```
{% for i in blog_info %}
    {{ i['url'] }}
    {{ i['post'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

The initial object returned from mongodb looking something like this...

```
[{u'category': u'python', u'status': u'published', u'title': u'working with python', u'url': u'working-with-python', u'date': u'April 2012', u'post': u'some blog post...', u'_id': ObjectId('553b719efec0c5546ed01dab')}]
```

It took me a while to figure out, I guess if it looks like a list, it doesn't actually mean it is one. :)